# no return for file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

why i not getting return on file_get_contents($myurl) but i do get output for wget

**updated:**

i use curl to get the return header and result and discovery that the it is on the header instead in of the body

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Document follows
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-type: text/plain
Server: XMS (724Solutions HTA XSAM_30_M2_B020 20070803.172831)
Date: Fri, 21 May 2010 10:48:31 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

HTTP/1.1 404 ChargedPartyNotAvailable
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-type: text/plain
Server: XMS (724Solutions HTA XSAM_30_M2_B020 20070803.172831)
Date: Fri, 21 May 2010 10:34:13 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

How can i extract out only "200 Document Follow" and "404 ChargedPartyNotAvailable" ?

Comment: Please show some code and explain in some more detail what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled in your php configuration?

However I would expect that you would get a warning generated if not - do you have errors/warnings displayed? You could add temporarily at the top of your script :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

and then you might see why file_get_contents() doesn't work.

**Edit**

You might just be able to use [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/get_headers) if you're only interested in headers.

Comment: +1 for allow_url_fopen and the error_reporting suggestion (though I would just log errors :p).

Comment: no problem with the configuration. it seems that the result is appear in the header not in the body

Comment: Yes you are right Tom. I only interested with the headers and mistook  file_get_contents($myurl) to get it.

Comment: @TomHaigh thx. didn't have error reporting on. i had a firewall issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP Curl package to retrieve the content of URL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$myUrl);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Or if you want to use only file_get_contents, check if you configured PHP.ini correctly

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

As mentioned here (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> A URL can be used as a filename with
>   this function if the fopen wrappers
>   have been enabled. See fopen()  for
>   more details on how to specify the
>   filename.

Comment: the PHP configuration is ok. it seem it appear only header instead of body

Comment: For those who want to use the variable `$result`, add this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` before `$result = curl_exec($ch)` first. Because as it is, the variable is quite useless. But still +1 for the short curl.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$contents = implode('', file($myurl));
```

I use it very often.