# PHP query does not show any results on apache webserver

Tags: php, html, json, apache2

Alright so. I have a relative simple task. Here is the fully functional working code of a query that does work. It works

```
<?php
$query = array(
    'address'=>'https://mcapi.ca/query/94.12.141.113:25577/info'); //Grab statistics from URL.
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($query['address']), true); //Decode the JSON response.
?>
```

It works. I've seen it work with my own two eyes.
The problem is now that I'm hosting the file. (obviously it has html code for the web page where the result of this query is called and displayed on the page(which also works)). When I host the file on my apache webserver which has been port forwarded and what have you - it's online. I go to the page.... scroll to the bottom and find that there are no results for this query. So my thinking is that apache is blocking links to other sites from within the files for some security reasons... sod that I want to see my results. So anyone know of such a setting? Maybe even a file that I can go and visit to change said setting?

Now what I want to know:
Is it the code?
if so how can I fix it?
Is it a setting in the webserver?
if so... you guessed it... how can I fix it?
and if it is none of the above... what is it?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

**This is the error log as requested**

```
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:42.055662 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\index.php on line 4
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:42.055662 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://mcapi.ca/query/94.12.141.113:25577/info): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\index.php on line 4
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:46.248600 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\gallery.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:46.248600 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://mcapi.ca/query/94.12.141.113:25577/info): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\gallery.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:47.697728 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\about.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/gallery.php
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:47.697728 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://mcapi.ca/query/94.12.141.113:25577/info): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\about.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/gallery.php
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:48.495928 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\index.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/about.php
    [Sun Jan 01 14:18:48.495928 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1068] [client ::1:49636] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://mcapi.ca/query/94.12.141.113:25577/info): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\index.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/about.php
    [Sun Jan 01 14:34:21.958403 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1084] [client ::1:49819] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\index.php on line 4
    [Sun Jan 01 14:34:21.958403 2017] [:error] [pid 5052:tid 1084] [client ::1:49819] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://mcapi.ca/query/94.12.141.113:25577/info): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\index.php on line 4
```

Comment: How do you output the result saved in `$response`? Because it works when I test it and add `var_dump($response);` on the end of the above script. So either it's a problem fetching the result, or you have an error in how you output the result. Also, what does your server's error-log say?

Comment: <h4>There are currently <b><?php echo $response['players']['online']; ?></b> online players out of a maximum of <b><?php echo $response['players']['max']; ?></b> players.</h4>

Comment: checkout this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880878/no-return-for-file-get-contents

Comment: Well, that should output the correct information, so you should checkout your server's logs to see if there is any errors, or at least turn on PHP error-display in the script, to see if anything is output directly. Because that works just fine here.

Comment: Ahmed Mobaraki Just checked out the link and yes allow_url_fopen is "On" in the php config.

Comment: please remove that preamble that I removed in an earlier edit: *"Thank you oh wonderful people. But I swear to god if anyone questions whether it works I'll eat them whole."* http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41419744/2 including the  snippet stuff, it's not meant for that type of code

Comment: I removed that preamble; add it back in and I'll flag it to a moderator and the question may get locked. I asked you nicely and waited 5 mins but nothing was done about it. Remember, I asked politely. There's no need for *"But I swear to god if anyone questions whether it works I'll eat them whole"*. It could have been worded differently.

Comment: The error explains what's wrong. Change the server configuration so it accepts https links.